# How to set Pinterest sourceURL and description using UIActivityViewController with Pinterest.sharextension

Tags: ios, ios8, pinterest, ios8-extension

For iOS 8, Pinterest has an share extension.  How do I set image source URL and description attributes?  I am using UIActivityViewController.  Do I create a custom class with UIImage, NSURL for sourceURL and NSString for description and return?  I'm not sure how Pinterest would know to set the source URL and description.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are implementing a `share` method on a `UIViewController` subclass, the code below should meet your expectations:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)share {
    NSString *textToShare = @"Hello Pinterest!";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://blank.org"];
    UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"so-logo"];
    NSArray *activityItems = @[textToShare, url, imageToShare];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: activityItems applicationActivities: nil];

    [self presentViewController: activityViewController animated: YES completion: nil];
}
```

**Swift (3.0.2)**

```
func share() {
    let textToShare = "Hello Pinterest!"
    let url = URL(string: "http://blank.org")!
    let imageToShare = UIImage(named: "so-logo")!
    let activityItems: [Any] = [textToShare, url, imageToShare]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And the results should be something like this:
[image]